# Issue with screen capture

Tags: c#, .net, image, c#-4.0

I have a button on which a click and it takes a screenshot which i display in my Picture Box. I dont face issue with this code:

```
private void btnScreenShot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            btnSave.Visible = true;
            sendto_bmpbox.Image = CaptureScreen();
        }
```

However when i loop the entire Form freezes and i cannot click on anything:

```
private void btnScreenShot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Freezes here
            btnSave.Visible = true;
            while(flag == 0)
            {
                 sendto_bmpbox.Image = CaptureScreen();
            }
        }
```

How do i fix this problem?

Comment: It's locking up because your blocking in your loop. If you want to be able to interact with your form during whatever this process is doing, you should throw the loop in another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `while()` is infinite. What makes `flag` change from capture to capture?

In case you want to infinitely capture the screen -  **never** use the main thread for such things, as it will cause it to hang and prevent your application from updating the UI.

Use the [BackgroundWorker class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for things like that, you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) example.

Comment: I want the loop to run infinitely..... i have another button which stops capture... and sets flag to non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnSave.Visible = true;

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadWork));
            thread.Start();
        }

        int flag = 0;

        private void threadWork()
        {
            while (flag == 0)
            {
                UpdateImage();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateImage()
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(UpdateImage);
            }
            else
            {
                sendto_bmpbox.Image = CaptureScreen();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd also dispose the old image. Else the GC will be very unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

Try Application.DoEvents in loop. I think this can help you...

```
private void btnScreenShot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Freezes here
            btnSave.Visible = true;
            while(flag == 0)
            {
                 Application.DoEvents();
                 sendto_bmpbox.Image = CaptureScreen();
            }
        }
```